# Bike Frame Identification

Tags: frames, identify-this-bike

Does anyone have any leads on what make/model/year of frame this is? I spotted this bike last summer and it's been nagging at me ever since. I love the design and am trying to track down who is responsible for it. I am not a frame connoisseur by nature, so am hoping to enlist the help of those who are.[image: Frame in Question]

Comment: Looks like a bitser overall - the road bike frame with flat bars is a giveaway.   The spinergy wheel looks nice but they had a penchant for sudden rapid complete failure.   This should be an answerable question.

Comment: Search for aluminum time trial/triathlon bikes and scroll through pics. That type of aero seat tube is very common, but the shapes of the top and down tube are somewhat distinct